# Cambios entre Swift 2 y Swift 3

Tags: swift2, swift3

¿Alguien conoce alguna pagina donde se muestren los cambios, especialmente funciones, entre Swift 2 y Swift 3?

Comment: Es bastante fácil de googlear esto, prueba `swift3 release notes` y `swift3 changelog` deberías encontrar toda la información que buscas, lamentablemente la mayoría en inglés.

Answer (score 3):

Primero, la página principal del proyecto:
https://swift.org/blog/swift-3-0-released/

Y después, con una simple búsqueda en Google:

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/swift3

http://www.appcoda.com/swift3-changes/